# How to "shrink" all the cells in TableView and expand the one clicked on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When you click on a cell inside a TableView, it will expand.
How I achieved this was with the following methods:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if ([self.topicsArray containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [self.topicsArray removeObject:indexPath];
}
else
{
    [_topicsArray addObject:indexPath];

}

[_tableView beginUpdates];
[_tableView endUpdates];

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat kExpandedCellHeight = 240;
CGFloat kNormalCellHeigh = 115;


    if ([_topicsArray containsObject:indexPath])
    {

        return kExpandedCellHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        return kNormalCellHeigh;
    }


}
```

What I cannot figure out how to do is - How to 'shrink' all the cells in  a TableView before I expand the one clicked on?!

Comment: try `[_tableView reloadData]` between `[_tableView beginUpdates];
[_tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: That doesn't do anything :(

Comment: try it after `endUpdates` it should work, this calls again the recalculation of heights

Comment: No,man..it doesnt do anything. The cell that was expanded before, stays expanded and the one I click expands as well

Answer (score 0):

aha i got it you dont remove the index from the array. try `[topicsArray removeAllObjects]` before

```
if ([self.topicsArray containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [self.topicsArray removeObject:indexPath];
}
else
{
    [_topicsArray addObject:indexPath];

}
```